# How to focs cursor in textbox when click the RepeatButton in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, setfocus, repeatbutton

```
 <Grid x:Name="BackSpaceButton">       
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_remove" Height="46" Margin="234,119,225,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" GotFocus="txt_remove_GotFocus" TabIndex="2"/>        
    <RepeatButton x:Name="rbtn_remove" Content="Backspace" Delay="400" Interval="200" Margin="415,124,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.667,0.854" Click="rbtn_remove_Click" LostMouseCapture="rbtn_remove_LostMouseCapture" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" TabIndex="2" />        
</Grid>
```

This design will be like below

[image]

```
public partial class Repeate : Window
{
    Control GetTextbox;
    TextBox GetInstance;
    public Repeate()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void rbtn_remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        GetInstance = GetTextbox as TextBox;
        if (GetTextbox != null)
        {

            string _CurrentValue = GetInstance.Text;
            var _CareIndex = GetInstance.CaretIndex;

            if (_CareIndex > 0)
            {
                string _Backspace = _CurrentValue.Remove(_CareIndex - 1, 1);
                GetInstance.Text = _Backspace;                   
                GetInstance.CaretIndex = _CareIndex - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void txt_remove_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetTextbox = (Control)sender;
    }

    private void rbtn_remove_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GetInstance.Focus();
    }


}
```

Out put will be like below

[image]

When i click the Backspace button textbox will remove and the cursor will be focusing in textbox.What is the issue is, when i click and hold the Backspace button the textbox value removing repeatedly but the cursor in not showing.

For **Ex:** Enter the value in textbox and then click and hold the backspace key from your system keyboard then you will fee the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code it will help you well.why because some day before i faced the same issue.

```
<Grid x:Name="BackSpaceButton">
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_remove" Height="46" Margin="234,119,225,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" GotFocus="txt_remove_GotFocus" TabIndex="2"/>        
    <RepeatButton x:Name="rbtn_remove" Focusable="False"  Content="Backspace" Delay="400" Interval="100" Margin="415,123,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.667,0.854" Click="rbtn_remove_Click" LostMouseCapture="rbtn_remove_LostMouseCapture" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66"/>        
</Grid>
```

in above code i just add one property **Focusable="False"**

```
 private void rbtn_remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetInstance = GetTextbox as TextBox;
        if (GetTextbox != null)
        {

            string _CurrentValue = GetInstance.Text;
            var _CareIndex = GetInstance.CaretIndex;

            if (_CareIndex > 0)
            {
                string _Backspace = _CurrentValue.Remove(_CareIndex - 1, 1);
                GetInstance.Text = _Backspace;                   
                GetInstance.Focus();
                GetInstance.CaretIndex = _CareIndex - 1;                   

            }
        }
    }
    void txt_remove_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetTextbox = (Control)sender;  
    }
    private void rbtn_remove_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GetInstance.Focus();
    }
```

in above code I've just added single code **GetInstance.Focus();**